# grep: No such file or directory for line in file

Tags: bash, grep

I'm trying to grep every line within a file, and for every match echo PASS, for every non match echo FAIL. I am getting a "no such file or directory" error, it seems to be trying to grep a file instead of the line I am passing within my loop?

File:

```
$ cat new.txt
TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256
TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA
TLS_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA
TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384
TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256
TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA
```

Failing script:

```
#!/bin/bash

while IFS= read -r line
do
    if grep -P 'TLS_RSA' $line; then
        echo "PASS."
    else
        echo "FAIL."
    fi
done < "new.txt"
```

When running a normal grep command against the file this is the output (expected):

```
$ grep -P 'TLS_RSA' new.txt
TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256
TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA
TLS_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA
```

Comment: Please add your desired output (no description) for that sample input to your question (no comment).

Comment: Apologies, I had edited my example to be simpler and made a typo when I was copying and pasting.

Comment: `awk '{ if ($0 ~ /TLS_RSA/) print "PASS"; else print "FAIL" }' new.txt` is an alternative.

Comment: Note that you don't need `IFS= ` since your read uses only 1 variable; `$line` will get the whole line anyway. And you don't need the `-P` option to `grep` since you don't use any Perl-specific regex features. But as suggested by Cyrus, you may want the `-q` (`--quiet`) option for grep to not print the matching lines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest to replace

```
if grep -P 'TLS_RSA' $line; then
```

with

```
if grep -q 'TLS_RSA' <<< "$line"; then
```

to feed grep's stdin with content of a variable.

Comment: Many thanks, this works! After a quick google it seems to be a "here string", something I had no idea about.

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/bin/bash
while IFS= read -r line; do
     grep -q 'TLS_RSA' <<< $line && echo "PASS."|| echo "FAIL."
done < "new.txt"
```

You need to replace the $line with <<< $line.

Also for the sake of cleaner code, you can also do away with the if statement and make it into a single line.

Comment: The cleanliness of the code is debatable — or is in the eye of the beholder.  I wouldn't format the code the way it is in the question; but I wouldn't use `&&` or `||` either.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use awk as an alternative to looping in a script

```
awk '{ print "grep -o \"TLS_RSA\" "$0" && echo -e \""$0"\nPASS\" || echo -e \""$0"\nFAIL\""  }' new.txt | bash
```

This prints the grep command for each line (file) in the new.txt file and then pipes the command through to bash to execute

As an alternative, you can use awk's built in system funtion and so:

```
awk '{ system("grep -o \"TLS_RSA\" "$0" && echo -e \""$0"\nPASS\" || echo -e \""$0"\nFAIL\"")  }' new.txt
```

NOTE - You need to be careful with command indirection examples such as these. It is important that you print and verify the command (i.e. run the command with piping through to bash in the first example) before executing the actual commands.

Answer (score 0):

You can do the same without `grep` but just built-in POSIX shell features:

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env sh

while IFS= read -r line
do
  case $line in
    *TLS_RSA*) printf %s\\n PASS.;;
    *) printf %s\\n FAIL.;;
  esac
done <new.txt
```